# Unblur content inside blurring background div

Tags: html, css, background-image, wallpaper

So I really like this kind of special effect here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_blurred_background.asp where you can blur out a background and have the text show up. The problem that I am currently having right now is that I want to add in another wallpaper for my second content below my first content. The first content is good. Now I want my second content to be in the second wallpaper as you scroll. Kind of like creating a parallax effect, but instead I am am creating my own unique website.

This time I want a blurring background (*wallpaper number two*) while having the stuff where I already want it placed and have it focus.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Starting where the `bg-image2`, I want the `h1`, and the `p`, inside `bg-image2` to focus over the blurring background image.

***NOTE:*** **The wallpaper will not show in the snippet below because I already got the pictures I need in my folder which is located in my computer.**

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("images/wallpaper1.jpg");
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-image2 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("images/wallpaper2.jpg");
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.profilePicture {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 200px auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image"></div>

<div class="bg-text">
  <h1>My name is Stackoverflow</h1>
  <p>And I am a website</p>
</div>


<div class="bg-image2">

  <!-- This is the part where I want my stuff to not be blurred and focus -->
    
  <div class="profilePicture">
    <img src="images/profilePic.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
    <h1>This is a title</h1>
    <p>This is just a paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you not just blur the background images with a filter (using something like Photoshop) before placing them as a background image and remove the filter css all together?

Comment: @KJEK-Code Right good point. I think I will just stick with styling a photo using another tool before making my website a bit complicated with all these crazy coding.

Comment: Best of Luck to you Azazel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that the result you are looking for?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exVRyy

All i did was to create a div around the `bg-image2` and `profilePicture`, so that the blur on `bg-image2` doesn't affect `profilePicture`, then set that div to `position:relative;` , so that the `profilePicture` can be placed in the middle like you did.

Here is your HTML edited:

```
<div class="bg-image"></div>

<div class="bg-text">
    <h1>My name is Stackoverflow</h1>
    <p>And I am a website</p>
</div>

<div class="bg-test">
  <div class="bg-image2">

    <!-- This is the part where I want my stuff to not be blurred and focus -->

  </div>

  <div class="profilePicture">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1253661/pexels-photo-1253661.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=android-wallpaper-bluhen-blume-1253661.jpg&fm=jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>This is just a paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507608616759-54f48f0af0ee?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */

.bg-test {
  position:relative;
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-image2 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://whatthenewsblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/ecl-ann.jpg");
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  /* Full height */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.profilePicture {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Nice clean example and lots of comments too. Good job.

Comment: It would be nice if you added the code to the answer here in SO to make it self-sufficient. If the Pen ever gets deleted and/or is not available, the answer becomes incomplete and thus useless for the community.

Comment: Well thought. Done!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue. After a lot of searches, I found the perfect solution.
You can use `backdrop-filter`.

Your code:

```css
body,
    html {


      height: 100%;
    }
    
    * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .bg-image {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507608616759-54f48f0af0ee?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
      /* Add the blur effect */
      
      /* Full height */
      height: 100%;
      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    
    /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
    
    .bg-test {
      position:relative;
    }
    
    .bg-text {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
      border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 2;
      width: 80%;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .bg-image2 {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("https://blog.prezi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/patrick-tomasso-208114-unsplash-1024x768.jpg");
      /* Add the blur effect */
      /* Full height */
      height: 100vh;
      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .profilePicture {
      backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      color: white;
      top:50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="bg-image">

<div class="bg-text">
    <h1>My name is Stackoverflow</h1>
    <p>And I am a website</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="bg-test">
  <div class="bg-image2">

    <!-- This is the part where I want my stuff to not be blurred and focus -->
    <div class="profilePicture">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1253661/pexels-photo-1253661.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=android-wallpaper-bluhen-blume-1253661.jpg&fm=jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>This is just a paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

I know its been so long since you asked and you got the answers.
Hope this will be helpful for someone else :)

I modified code from [cryptomothy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9253573/cryptomothy)